# average of a field with running total in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently using following MySQL query to obtain a running total and return it on a condition

```
SELECT id, @rn as total
FROM table
JOIN (
SELECT @rn :=0
)rn
WHERE (
@rn := @rn + amount
) > 130
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The table is simply as follows

```
id  | amount | rate
20  |  120   | 5.2
21  |  22    | 6.1
22  |  16    | 3.8
```

Now I want to select (with the query above) also average or the `rate` field of the rows which were used to add up the running total; i.e. currently the query above will return:

```
id  | total
21  |  142
```

However I would like to return

```
id  | total | avg_rate
21  |  142   | 5.65
```

I have tried to simply select `AVG(rate)`, but that always returns average of all the rows, rather than only the ones added up in the running total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some playing with the user variables here is the solution, essentially I needed to track both the amount running total, and also the rate running total along with row numbers to work out the average with user set variables. I considered avoiding this query selecting all the rows and then working out the averages with PHP, however I believe this will be more portable and scalable.

```
SELECT t.id, @rn , @avg_rate , @num_rows , ROUND( @avg_rate / @num_rows , 2 )
FROM (

SELECT @rn :=0, @avg_rate :=0, @num_rows :=0
)d
JOIN (

SELECT id, amount, rate
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
)t
WHERE (
@num_rows := @num_rows +1
)
AND (
@avg_rate := @avg_rate + t.rate
)
AND (
@rn := @rn + t.amount
) > 150
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you are not using SQL2012, this may help you or others:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    Id      int,
    Amount  decimal(18,2),
    Rate    decimal(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(20, 120, 5.2)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(21, 22, 6.1)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(22, 16, 3.8)

select Id, 
    Amount,
    Rate,
    sum(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Id
                      ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTotal,
    avg(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY Id 
                    ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningAvg
FROM @myTable
```

Here are the results:

```
Id  Amount  Rate    RunningTotal    RunningAvg
20  120.00  5.20    120.00  5.200000
21  22.00   6.10    142.00  5.650000
22  16.00   3.80    158.00  5.033333
```

Otherwise, here is a [decent link](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/rolling_sums_in_mysql_followup.html) explaining running totals and averages.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am using MySQL so I can't use the query you provided, however the link was helpful

Comment: There is no such thing as "SQL 2012". Do you happen to mean "SQL **Server** 2012"? And window functions  with a running total wasn't introduced by SQL Server. That has been part of the SQL standard for over 10 years now and Oracle could do that even longer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - lol, ok, Structured Query Language Server 2012, better?